# How can i call to my custom module in other module?

Tags: magento2

I have the next problem:

I do a simple custom module, the typical Hello World, i can access with

```
http://localhost/hello/index/index
```

and i can see my module.

The problem is the next, How can i call my module from another module?

In magento 1.x i had in this file:

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/page/3columns.phtml` and i call my module with: `<div class="prueba"> <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('holamundo/holamundo.phtml')->toHtml(); ?></div>
```

In magento 2 this folder don't exist, how can i call like in magento 1.x?

Comment: Could you add a bit more about what you are trying to achieve? If you are always creating a child block, normally you create a block using a layout file. It might be there is a different approach that you should use, but hard to suggest without a bit more depth of your goal.